# Adding new objects to a clientside array - best practices?

Tags: javascript

Say you have a list of "vehicles" - you have an observableArray of these ko.observable()s.

You let your user add a new vehicle with the following:

```
var emptyVehicle = {
    "make": "chevrolet",
    "model": "corvette"
};
app.on('CLICKED_ADD_VEHICLE', function () {
            var vehicle = new vehicleViewModel(emptyVehicle);
            vehicle.hasWheels(true);
            innerModel.sets.push(set);
        });
```

If they save the vehicle, you get a real vehicle from your dataservice, and then replace the blank one with this:

```
app.on('CLICKED_SAVE', function (oldVehicle) {
            var newVehicle = new vehicleViewModel(dataservice.createVehicle(oldVehicle));
                    innerModel.vehicles.remove(oldVehicle);
                    innerModel.vehicles.push(newVehicle);
        });
```

I know I'm leaving some code out here, but this is more of a practices/approach question than a code question.  Is this an acceptable approach to adding new items to a list?  New up a temporary template, and throw it away in place of an actual item if the user saves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's acceptable, but it's not really preferred.  What happens if someone changes the code latter on, and it fails to send `oldVehicle`?  What happens if the `CLICKED_SAVE` event is triggered again?  What happens if the AJAZ call itself just fails?

Better practice is to design your app to begin with an empty `innerModel.vehicles` array, and then have `addVehicle` be a method of `app` that spools up a new `vechicleViewModel` and pushes it to the array.

Generally, events should call methods, even if they aren't UI events, unless you have a good reason not to.